# Exchange 2010 DAG Failover Cluster DNS Issues

Tags: exchange-2010, high-availability, dag

I am having an issues with my Exchange 2010 servers. I have two servers that have HUB/CAS/MAILBOX installed on them. They are configured to use DAG failover cluster.

I expereienced an issue recently where the DNS entry for the DAG and the MAIL01 server where missing from DNS on the Domain Controllers. I am not sure how they disappeared. I read online that a way to fix the issue was to recreate the DAG DNS and make sure it has special permissions so that the two mail servers can update the DNS entry. That didn't work. I also recreated the DNS entry for the MAIL01 server.

When I run the Cluster /List command from the command prompt the cluster DAG is listed twice.

On the Active Node of the Cluster I get the following events:

Log Name: System
 Source: Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering
 Date: 2/12/2013 9:09:03 AM
 Event ID: 1196
 Task Category: Network Name Resource
 Level: Error
 Keywords: 
User: SYSTEM
 Computer: MAIL01.domain.local
 Description:
 Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' failed registration of one or more associated DNS name(s) for the following reason:
 DNS operation refused.
 .

Ensure that the network adapters associated with dependent IP address resources are configured with at least one accessible DNS server.
 Event Xml:

Log Name: System
 Source: Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering
 Date: 2/12/2013 9:09:03 AM
 Event ID: 1579
 Task Category: Network Name Resource
 Level: Warning
 Keywords: 
User: SYSTEM
 Computer: MAIL01.domain.local
 Description:
 Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' failed to update the DNS record for name 'DAG.domain.local' over adapter 'MAPI'. The error code was 'DNS operation refused. (9005)'. Ensure that a DNS server is accessible from this cluster node and contact your DNS server administrator to verify the cluster identity can update the DNS record 'DAG.domain.local'.

I need some help with this issue and any suggestions would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

Because the Mailbox servers are configured with dual interfaces it is important to make sure that the secondary interface is not configured to register itself in DNS. If this isn´t the case it might be that you see exactly the issues you have currently.

[Source URL](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-2010-database-availability-group-installation-step-by-step/)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following document:

Event ID 1579 — Network Name Resource Availability

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830298(WS.10).aspx

hope it helps!